# Fermat's Last Theorem for $n=4$ revisited

Tags: diophantine-equations

Fermat's Last Theorem for $n=4$ states that 
If $$b^4+c^4=a^4\tag{1}$$
Then, no positive integers $a, b, c$ exist simultaneously. 
We can re-arrange (1) as
$$a^4-b^4=c^4\tag{2}$$
But, by direct expansion, we see that
$$a^4-b^4 = (a^2+b^2)^2-(b(a+b))^2-(b(a-b))^2\tag{3}$$
So, equating (2) and (3), we get
$$c^4 = (a^2+b^2)^2-(b(a+b))^2-(b(a-b))^2$$
$$(c^2)^2 = (a^2+b^2)^2-(b(a+b))^2-(b(a-b))^2$$
$$(c^2)^2+(b(a+b))^2+(b(a-b))^2 = (a^2+b^2)^2\tag{4}$$
We can see that (4) is a Pythagoras' quadruple.
Pythagoras' quadruple states that
If $$w=m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2$$
$$x=2(mq+np)$$
$$y=2(nq-mp)$$
$$z=m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2$$
Then
$$w^2+x^2+y^2=z^2\tag{5}$$
Where $gcd(w,x,y,z)=1$
Since $w,x,y,z$ are co-prime, then $w$ and $z$ are odd while $x$ and $y$ are even.
This shows that two of $b(a+b)$, $b(a-b)$ and $a^2+b^2$ must be even while the remaining one is odd.
Now, comparing (4) and (5), we can see that
$$(c^2)^2=m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2$$
Thus, $c$ is odd. And if $c$ is odd, then we see from (2) that $a$ and $b$ must be of opposite parity. But $b$ can't be odd because then, $b(a+b)$, $b(a-b)$ and $a^2+b^2$ will all be odd which does not conform with Pythagoras' quadruple. 
If $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, we see that $b(a+b)$ is even, $b(a-b)$ is even and $a^2+b^2$ is odd which corresponds with Pythagoras' quadruple.
So, we are forced to conclude that $a$ is odd while $b$ is even. 
Now, we can see that
$$(c^2)^2=m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2\tag{6}$$
$$a^2+b^2=m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2\tag{7}$$
$$b(a+b)=2(mq+np)\tag{8}$$
$$b(a-b)=2(nq-mp)\tag{9}$$
Adding (8) and (9), we have
$$b(a+b) + b(a-b)=2(mq+np)+ 2(nq-mp)$$
$$b(a+b) + b(a-b)=2q(n+m)+ 2p(n-m)\tag{10}$$
We can see that to make both expressions of (10) obviously equal, we only need to set $p=q=\frac{m}{2}$. By doing this, we have
$$b(a+b) + b(a-b)=2\frac{m}{2}(n+m)+ 2\frac{m}{2}(n-m)$$
$$b(a+b) + b(a-b)=m(n+m)+ m(n-m)\tag{11}$$
Comparing both sides of (11), we can see that $b=m$ and $a=n$. Specifically, $m$ is even while $n$ is odd. 
Putting $p=q=\frac{m}{2}$ in (6) gives
$$(c^2)^2=m^2+n^2-(\frac{m}{2})^2-(\frac{m}{2})^2$$
$$(c^2)^2=m^2+n^2-\frac{m^2}{2}$$
$$(c^2)^2=\frac{m^2}{2}+n^2$$
Since $m$ is even, say $m=2m_1$, then
$$(c^2)^2=2{m_1}^2+n^2$$
$$c^4=2{m_1}^2+n^2\tag{12}$$
Also, putting $p=q=\frac{m}{2}$ in (7) gives
$$a^2+b^2=m^2+n^2+(\frac{m}{2})^2+(\frac{m}{2})^2$$
$$a^2+b^2=m^2+n^2+\frac{m^2}{2}$$
$$a^2+b^2=\frac{3m^2}{2}+n^2$$
Since $m$ is even, say $m=2m_1$, then
$$a^2+b^2=6{m_1}^2+n^2\tag{13}$$
The final jigsaw is now to prove that at least one of (12) and (13) does not have integers solution.
Putting $a=n$, $b=m=2m_1$ in (13), we have;
$$n^2+(2m_1)^2=6{m_1}^2+n^2$$
$$4m_1^2=6{m_1}^2$$
$$2m_1^2= 0$$
Thus we have that $m_1=m=p=q=b=0$ which means (1) becomes
$$0^4+c^4=a^4$$ which is trivial. This makes us conclude that no three natural numbers satisfy (1)\

**LATEST DEVELOPMENT**
Let's begin a new approach with (6) and (7).
From (7), we need to know that $a^2+b^2>m^2+n^2$ since $p$ and $q$ cannot be equal to zero simultaneously, because then, we will have a trivial pythagoras quadruple.
Now, suppose (6) and (7) could exist simultaneously, multiplying them together gives
$$c^2(a^2+b^2)=(m^2+n^2)^2-(p^2+q^2)^2$$
$$(ac)^2+(bc)^2=(m^2+n^2)^2-(p^2+q^2)^2$$
$$(ac)^2+(bc)^2+(p^2+q^2)^2=(m^2+n^2)^2\tag{8}$$

We can see that (8) is a new Pythagoras quadruple which is less than (5) since $a^2+b^2=m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2>m^2+n^2$.
Since (8) is a Pythagoras quadruple, we may say that
$$ac=m_1^2+n_1^2-p_1^2-q_1^2\tag{9}$$ since $a$ and $c$ are odd. 
We should note from (6) that since $m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2$ is always a perfect square, $m_1^2+n_1^2-p_1^2-q_1^2$ is also a perfect square. Hence, (9) becomes
$$(a_1c_1)^2= m_1^2+n_1^2-p_1^2-q_1^2\tag{10}$$
and
$$m^2+n^2=m_1^2+n_1^2+p_1^2+q_1^2\tag{11}$$
$$p^2+q^2=2(m_1q_1+n_1p_1)\tag{12}$$
$$bc=2(n_1q_1-m_1p_1)\tag{13}$$

From (11), we see that $a^2+b^2>m^2+n^2>m_1^2+n_1^2$ since $p_1$ and $q_1$ cannot be equal to zero simultaneously, because then, we will have a trivial pythagoras quadruple.
Now, multiplying (10) and (11) again leads to another pythagoras quadruple. This means that $a^2+b^2$ will keep decreasing on every new Pythagoras quadruple derived (i.e $$a^2+b^2>m^2+n^2>m_1^2+n_1^2>...>m_r^2+n_r^2$$
However, $a^2+b^2$ can't decrease forever which means that (6) and (7) cannot exist simultaneously, hence a contradiction that they can.

> **Question:** Is my new approach correct? If not, where is/are the flaw(s)?

Comment: what is $m_1$ as opposed to $m$?

Comment: Since $m$ is even, we can say $m=2m_1$ and substitute that.

Comment: Why do you think that all solutions of $(5)$ are given by the parametrization of $w,x,y,z$ by $m,n,p,q$? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple&ved=2ahUKEwiKzsH91ZTxAhWJ5OAKHQJLDEgQFjAAegQIBRAC&usg=AOvVaw1fERdxjYT2sf9_tVsqEDKe&cshid=1623589486963

Comment: 1. After $(7)$, why do you exclude 
$$b(a+b)=2(nq-mp)\\
b(a-b)=2(mq+np)$$ 
2. After $(8)$ you set
$p=q=\frac{m}{2}$ and finally get a contradiction. But how do you justify to set $p$ and $q$ to this value.
3. From $(9)$ you conclude $b=m$ and $a=n$. How to you justify this?

Comment: @miracle173, including $$b(a+b)=2(nq-mp)\\
b(a-b)=2(mq+np)$$ won't have mattered in the end because (8) and (9) are added which would have pretty yielded the same result if your claim is used. From $11$, it is easy to conclude that $a=n$ and $b=m$ because both sides of (11) have the same expression but different variables. On justifying $p=q=\frac{m}{2}$, I think I need to do better by figuring out why I made that assumption. My initial thought was to make both (8) and (9) fit together but now, I think I might have broken some rules there. I have made some changes above, kindly check again.

Comment: To clarify your third question more, simplifying $11$ further would have yielded $ab=mn$, which would make us even say $a=m$, $b=n$ such that $m$ is odd and $n$ is even since $a$ and $b$ are odd and even respectively. This doesn't really change anything other than $m$ is switched for $n$. All in all, we would have arrived at the same conclusion.

Comment: "From 11, it is easy to conclude that a=n and b=m because both sides of (11) have the same expression but different variables."  No, that kind of conclusion is not allowed. (11) is equivalent to ab=mn. You can see a simple counterexample is a=15,b=7,m=5,n=21

Comment: Oops! I guess the problem started with making $p=q=\frac{m}{2}$. Thanks for getting that spot on but could you suggest a way forward from (10)?

Comment: sorry @ShuaibLateef , I don't know, how to continue

Comment: here is a link to a proof for n=4  https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numberfield/fermatn4.html

Comment: I have visited that link before. I was just trying to find my own method. Thanks anyway.